# How do I calculate the grid width to fit When an item is larger than a column?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a grid the size of the image. which size can be reduced and expanded

[image]

I have 6 items in grid.

[image]

Each item is larger than the column of the grid.

I would like to set the width of the grid as shown in the image. How should I calculate?

[image]

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      zIndex: {
        1: 1,
        2: 2,
        3: 3,
        4: 4,
        5: 5,
        6: 6,
        7: 7,
        8: 8,
        9: 9,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="w-64 bg-red-200 p-4">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-6 relative">
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-10">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-9">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-8">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-7">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-6">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-5">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or stackblitz please?

Comment: @Pieterjan Yes, please wait.

Comment: @Pieterjan https://jsfiddle.net/akoneko47/pz9jmedt/10/

Answer (score 1):

You could consider applying `width: max-content` via the `w-max` from Tailwind. The [`max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content) keyword "represents the intrinsic maximum width or height of the content".

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      zIndex: {
        1: 1,
        2: 2,
        3: 3,
        4: 4,
        5: 5,
        6: 6,
        7: 7,
        8: 8,
        9: 9,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="w-max bg-red-200 p-4">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-6 relative">
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-10">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-9">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-8">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-7">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-6">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
    <div class="absolute w-20 aspect-[2/3] rounded-sm inline-block overflow-hidden relative z-5">
      <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/original/wZp8xcADdOZ0FK6FEEtrKXjjdKJ.jpg" alt="" class="w-full h-full">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```